# Registry editing - keys don't save before app is closed

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

I'm writing an auto start-up for my application but I'm running into problems if the app doesn't get closed gracefully before reboot, the keys are lost. I was working with RegCloseKey first, which I now changed to RegFlushKey but it's still not working. What do I have to add to write to the registry right away ?

```
     WriteReg PROC 
          invoke RegCreateKeyExW,HKEY_CURRENT_USER,offset regkey,NULL,NULL,REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,KEY_ALL_ACCESS,NULL,offset hIDKey,NULL
          .IF eax==ERROR_SUCCESS
            invoke lstrlenW,offset buf
            add eax,eax
            add eax,2
            invoke RegSetValueExW,hIDKey,offset keyname,NULL,REG_SZ,offset buf,eax
            invoke RegFlushKey,hIDKey
          .ENDIF 
 ret 
 WriteReg ENDP
```

Comment: So does the key get set at all?

Comment: Yes it does, I can reboot if I close the app first, the key will still be there, if I just reboot or hard-reset without closing the app first, the key is lost.

Comment: I forgot to add, does regedit see the new value immediately or not until you close the app?

Comment: My guess is that the program doesn't call WriteReg until it exits.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN states :

> If the function succeeds, the return value is ERROR_SUCCESS.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is a nonzero error code defined in Winerror.h.

Did you checked what value is returned by `RegCreateKeyExW`? You could have e.g. an access right problem.

Same is the `RegSetValueEx` call : does it returns `ERROR_SUCCESS`?

As general thumb rule, you should *always* check codes returned by API calls.